laravel octane reverse proxy apache
I’m having an issue with Laravel Octane. I’ve configured it with host 127.0.0.1 on port 8080 and set up a reverse proxy using Apache with the following additional configuration in the .htaccess file:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]

The data serving works without any problems, but for static files, when using Storage::url(), the host appears as http://127.0.0.1:8080

You can set  APP_URL environment variable in your .env file to match the external URL users will access (e.g., your domain name) i.e. APP_URL=http://yourdomain.com.try this and let me know.
